# No module named tensorflow even after it is present in the local

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter

I am already having tensorflow in my anaconda.Still when i run the ipython notebook ,it shows No module named tensorflow.

Comment: can you inclde the output of `conda list` command ?

Comment: anaconda has different environment and if you accessing it from outside then you need to install it using pip or easy_install

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Virtual Environment?

If yes, there might be difference in version.
try "pip install ipython", and then import tensorflow.

May it works.

Comment: I am already having tensforflow in the anaconda installed.tried !pip3 show tensorflow: and the following lines are shown,Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.4.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: c:\users\prajna.neerchal\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages
Requires: protobuf, wheel, numpy, six, enum34, tensorflow-tensorboard

Answer (score 0):

Its done...tried installing within the environment Tensorflow.